# MSVC single cpp file never finishes compiling

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-optimization

There's a single cpp file in a project, which, when optimizations are enabled, hasn't yet finished compiling for me after 20 minutes or so. I have narrowed it down to somewhere in its include hierarchy, but the reason for this still isn't quite apparent. Is there a setting somewhere in the compiler that might help me narrow down the function that is taking so long to compile? I have tried setting the MSBuild project build log file verbosity to Diagnostic, but, unfortunately, this causes the compiler to run out of memory and terminate after a few seconds.

Comment: Getting it to bomb even when changing MSBuild verbosity is a strong hint that you need to shop for another machine.

Comment: Not likely. Ryzen 3900x 12 core CPU. 64 GB RAM, and this happens to everyone else on my team. This is a compiler issue for sure. I don't expect to fix it myself, but I'd like to work around it by changing the code. Just need to figure out what code to change first.

Comment: Did you try compiling with '/showIncludes'? Also try raising your warning level, the extra warnings may give you clues